# What does thread's idle time mean in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

What is the meaning of idle time with respect to threads in Java?
I'm reading [Java The Complete Reference 8th edition's](https://www.mhprofessional.com/9780071606301-usa-java-the-complete-reference-8th-edition-group) and
it says something like this:

> ...One thread can pause without stopping other parts of your program.
>   For example, the idle time created when a thread reads data from a
>   network or waits for user input can be utilized elsewhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it means the thread's state is [`WAITING`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.State.html#WAITING) or [`TIMED_WAITING`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.State.html#TIMED_WAITING), which means

> A thread in the waiting state is waiting for another thread to perform
>   a particular action.

Comment: I didn't understand what is idle because I'm not a native english speaker, so if I understood well the 'idle' means the time that a thread is waiting?

Comment: @LuizFernando, Yes. The English word, "Idle" means "Not busy," "not working," or "not in-use." It often has a negative connotation, E.g., "That person over there should not be _idle_, he should be working!" or, "That machine is _idle_ far too often, we should find a way to make some money with it, or we should sell it."

Answer (score 1):

Imagine there is only one CPU. There are two things the user wants to do.

1) Download song and play it (lets say song download takes 10 sec to get network connection download it for 5 seconds, and plays for 60 seconds).
2) Copy another file from one folder to another (lets say file copy takes 3 seconds).

In this case, if there is only one thread, then that thread waits for 10 sec to get connection, and 5 sec to download, play the song for 60 seconds and then copy another file for 3 seconds.

In all this, when the thread is waiting for 10 sec to obtain a network connection, nothing is being done until it actually gets the connection, and is just idle doing nothing. Now, when a thread is idle, the CPU is not being used. Now, when this is the case, should there be another thread, then that thread could have been used for the 3 second file copy when the first thread is waiting for 10 sec in order to obtain a network connection.

In the first case, 10 sec is called idle time

Answer (score 1):

I can try to explain it further with an example that contains a series of events.

A simple program *reads* user input, *writes* it to database, and *reports* status back to the user.

**Sequence of operations:**

1. Read user IO [`thread A`]
2. Process it and write to database [`thread B`]
3. Reports status back to user [`thread A`]

In above `thread A` will pause after sequence `1` until it is unblock by `thread B`. So while sequence `2` is going on `thread A` is in idle state.

Answer (score 1):

A thread can be in 2 states: idle state or working state. A working thread occupies a CPU and executes some program. An idle thread does not occupy a CPU, only core memory. Any idle thread is waiting for some event, and so is linked to corresponding event queue.

For example, a monitor has 2 queues: one for threads trying to execute `synchronized` statement, and the other for threads who invoked `Object.wait()` method.

When the event happens, one or all threads are taken from the event queue and put to the processor queue, where they wait a CPU to become free. When a CPU becomes free, it takes next thread from the processor queue and starts to execute its code from the place it asked for some event, and got to the queue.

Actual states of JVM threads differ from this simplified picture.